# AUDACIOUS PLAYER- Direct DSD reproduction?

Tags: audacious

My setup: PC Linux based (Q4OS 3.11.1) connected to Topping D90 DAC and Audacious player.
I am able to play any type of file at any sample rate, DAC-display reports it properly.
Except for DSD files. It looks like they are converted into PCM.
Is it possible to configure Audacious to directly transmit DSD files to DAC, without converting them?
Thank you.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audacious supports only PCM, not DSD. The supported formats are:

```
enum {
 FMT_FLOAT,
 FMT_S8, FMT_U8,
 FMT_S16_LE, FMT_S16_BE, FMT_U16_LE, FMT_U16_BE,
 FMT_S24_LE, FMT_S24_BE, FMT_U24_LE, FMT_U24_BE, /* padded to 4 bytes */
 FMT_S32_LE, FMT_S32_BE, FMT_U32_LE, FMT_U32_BE,
 FMT_S24_3LE, FMT_S24_3BE, FMT_U24_3LE, FMT_U24_3BE }; /* packed in 3 bytes */
```

Source: https://github.com/audacious-media-player/audacious/blob/master/src/libaudcore/audio.h.in#L25

Comment: Good to know, it's a shame. Any recommendation for a DSD player? Thank you

Comment: I know different people feel strongly about this, but my recommendation is not to worry about DSD vs. PCM, and just use the player you like the most. Your ears are not hearing either: they are hearing an analog signal. Either digital format can encode that analog signal with a fidelity far exceeding what any human ear can hear.

Comment: If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!